# Send async response and don't get zombie pids

Tags: http, go

I'm aiming for curl client sends http req to Go API and Go API does (1. run a background shell, 2. returns response to client instantly  but 3. keeps on running the point 1 server-side command in the background). Problem is point 2 is not being returned to client instantly, client is only getting a response after point 3 finishes

I tried:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "flag"
    "strconv"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/go-ldap/ldap"
    "regexp"
    "errors"
    "encoding/base64"
    "time"
)
func insert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (error) {
fullcmd := fmt.Sprintf("/home/ec2-user/spark_home/bin/spark-submit %s", "dgs")
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", fullcmd)
err4 := cmd.Start()

if err4 != nil {
    e1 := fmt.Sprintf("Error")
    l.Printf(e1)
    http.Error(w, e1, http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return err4
}  else {
    l.Printf("The data is being ingested asynchronously in the background \n")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "request received. The data is being ingested asynchronously in the background \n")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("request received. The data is being ingested asynchronously in the background \n")))
}

//wait for the spark command to finish, need to Wait() otherwise zombie/orphan pid is created
cmd.Wait()

//do bunch of other commands here that take 30+ seconds

l.Printf("success")
    return nil
}

r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/test", insert).Methods(http.MethodPost)
    http.Handle("/", r)  

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":" + strconv.Itoa(*port),
        Handler:    handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, http.DefaultServeMux),
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    }     
    server.ListenAndServeTLS(TLS_SERVER_CERTFILE, TLS_SERVER_KEYFILE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response will be completed when the HTTP handler returns, so if you want to start a job that will continue, you have to do that in a separate goroutine. You can start the goroutine as soon as the shell process starts, using something like this:

```
func insert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (error) {
...
err4 := cmd.Start()

if err4 != nil {
  ...
}  
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
fmt.Fprintf(w, "request received. The data is being ingested asynchronously in the background \n")

go func() {
   cmd.Wait()
   // Do other stuff
}()
return nil
}
```

Comment: just to help me understand goroutines more, can 'Do other stuff' bit use variables set before 'go func()' bit ? also if 2 http requests are sent in parallel with different http input args, is each request completely isolated or could the go server mistakenly send wrong variables to the goroutine?

Comment: Code in the goroutine can see the variables visible at the point it is started. For the code in the answer, goroutine sees w, r, err4, and anything declared above it. Concurrent http request handlers execute in their own goroutines, they are isolated.